# New Case Alert triggered when existing Record edited

Tags: workflow, case, email2case, email-alert, case-object

Anytime a Case's fields are edited, our Salesforce's instance will send out a 'New Case Alert' even though that Case is pre-existing, and a user only edited the record.

We have an Email-to-Case system setup, along with an Email Ref ID for tracking email threads, and Workflow Rules that Field Update a Case based on keywords in the email body.

Here's the workflow rule that triggers the 'New Case Created' Email Alert:

```
Case: Case Record Type **not equal to** Questionnaire
```

I thought this was previously resolved, but we just creared new custom fields for Case Page Layouts, and when we started editing the fields on existing records, we noticed 'New Case Alerts' were firing off.

Our Salesforce Instance also does not currently have any case management setup.

Does it make sense to try writing a Logical Formula, that only kicks off a new alert if CreatedDate is equal to TODAY and not equal to the record type?

Comment: which of the three workflow triggering conditions are you using: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules_configure_settings.htm&language=en_US ?

Comment: Right now, the third Condition: 'created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria'

Comment: @crop1645 I haven't had problems with just defaulting to this third Conditional, and I don't fully understand the difference between this third condition and the second 'created, and every time it’s edited.'

Comment: well, unless you have workflows/processes/triggers that are setting and resetting the `recordType`, the workflow shouldn't trigger given  you have `'created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria`. If you  look in the debug log, you can trace the workflows that actually execute and this might yield insight

Comment: I have a Debug Log enabled for the account that was triggering the alerts, but how do I drill into the Log?

Comment: GPP - analyzing a debug log is a whole topic in itself but if you search for WORKFLOW or EMAIL you'll see where these events occur.